How to save the buttons added to the spreadsheet in the VSTO project
My project requires adding a button to the Excel sheet, similar to the simplified code below. But once the sheet is closed and opened again, the button cannot be clicked. How can I save the status of this button so that it can be retained every time I open this spreadsheet?
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Tools = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class Ribbon
    {
        private void Ribbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Tools.Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);

            string buttonName = "MyButton";

            RibbonButton clickedButton = sender as RibbonButton;
            if (clickedButton != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Button added");
                Excel.Range selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Excel.Range;
                if (selection != null)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button button =
     new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
                    button.Text = "Click Me";
                    button.Click += Button_Click; 
                    var addedButton = worksheet.Controls.AddControl(button, selection, buttonName);
                    addedButton.AutoLoad = true;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                worksheet.Controls.Remove(buttonName);
            }
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button was clicked!");
        }
    }
}


Due to the large number of buttons that need to be added to multiple sheets in my project, I tried to add a WorkbookBeforeSave event, but I don't know how to traverse my buttons, save them for status, and reload their status the next time I open them.
How to solve it? Thanks.
